# Prove the value of a function with odd and even function properties

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, proof-verification

Question :

> Given
>   $$f(x)+\frac{f(-x)}{2}=2x\,,\quad x\ne 0$$
>
> Solve for : $f(2)$

My work :

Let

$$a=f(x)$$

$$b=\frac{f(-x)}{2}$$

Consider $a+b=2x\,,\quad x\in\Bbb N$

Then, there are two possibilities

- $a$ is even and $b$ is even
- $a$ is odd and $b$ is odd

For case $a$ is even and $b$ is even :

$$f(-x)=f(x)$$

$$\begin{align}
&2f(2)+f(2)=8\\
&f(2)=\dfrac{8}{3}
\end{align}$$

For case $a$ is odd and $b$ is odd :

$$f(-x)=-f(x)$$

$$\begin{align}
&2f(2)-f(2)=8\\
&f(2)=8
\end{align}$$

But, my friend told me that she just found one unique solution that is $8$ using elimination method.

Which is true?

Please correct my work. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the idea here is first to show that $f$ is odd and then to use this property to find $f(2)$:

We have

- $f(x) + \frac{f(-x)}{2} = 2x$ for $x \neq 0$
- $f(-x) + \frac{f(x)}{2} = -2x$ for $x \neq 0$

Adding those two equations gives
$$\frac{3}{2}\left(f(x) + f(-x) \right) = 0 \Rightarrow f(-x) = -f(x) \mbox{ for } x\neq 0$$

So, $f$ is odd.

Now, you use this and obtain
$$f(2) + \frac{f(-2)}{2} = 4 \Leftrightarrow f(2) -\frac{f(2)}{2}=4 \Leftrightarrow \boxed{f(2) = 8}$$

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you change $x$ to $-x$ and solve the two equations together you get $f(x)=4x$. So $8$ is the right answer. Sorry, I really don't know what you are doing in your first method. [It is  not even mentioned that $f$ is  a function on the integers, so what do even and odd mean]?

PS: a function $f$ on the real line is called an odd function if $f(-x)=-f(x)$ and it is called even if $f(-x)=f(x)$. This has nothing to do with even and odd integers.

Comment: Actually i was thinking about integer is a subset of real number. But i don't know what the idea behind this question for all real numbers which are not integers.

Comment: @user516076 Change $x$ to $-x$ to get a second equation; write $f(-x)$ as $2[f(x)-2x]$ and plug this into the second equation. You will now be able to see that $f(x)=4x$.

Comment: Ok... if i change $x$ to $-x$, is that mean i claim that my function is even no matter what the function is? Or that is so?

Comment: You are given an equation which holds for any $x \neq 0$ so you have full freedom to apply it with $x$ changed to $-x$.